# Como multiplico un string por N veces en javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Buena noches, tengo una duda, necesito que al ingresar un numero en javascript lo imprima en consola por la cantidad ingresada. Por ejemplo si quisiera que el string sea un asterisco "*": 
Si ingreso un numero 5, el resultado debe de ser: *****.

Algo que funcione así:
5 * "*" = *****

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado? Que errores has tenido?  Muestranos como has intentado hacerlos.Puedes pasarte por el [tour] y por [ask]

Answer (score 6):

El método `str.repeat` hará eso por ti:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
str.repeat(2);
```

Resultado: Hello world!Hello world!

Si quieres multiplicar números simplemente será como una multiplicación normal

Comment: Cuidado. El método repeat del objeto String es parte del estándar ES6 y aún no está implementado en todos los navegadores.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que buscaba :D

Answer (score 2):

Un workaround muy utilizado en tu caso es el de utilizar el método join del objeto Array:

```js
function calcularResultado(){
  var caracter = $('#caracter').val();
  var repeticiones = parseInt($('#repeticiones').val());
  if (caracter.length!==1 || isNaN(repeticiones)) { 
    $('#resultado').text = '';
    return; 
  }

  $('#resultado').text(Array(repeticiones + 1).join(caracter));
}

$(function(){
  $('#caracter').on('keyup', calcularResultado);
  $('#repeticiones').on('keyup', calcularResultado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Carácter: <input id="caracter" type="text" maxlength="1" placeholder="Introduce carácter" /><br /><br />
Número: <input id="repeticiones" type="number" placeholder="Nº de repeticiones" /><br /><br />
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Espero que ésto te sirva. Saludos.

```js
function Concatenar_String(A_Repetir, Num_Veces)
{
   for(var i = 0; i < Num_Veces; i ++)
   {
      Valor_Final += A_Repetir;
   } 
   return Valor_Final;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo lo hice de la siguiente manera y me gustaría compartirlo, capaz a alguien le pueda servir.
Lo hice usando recursividad (recursion).

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
return num <= 0 ? str = " " : str + repeatStringNumTimes(str, num - 1) ;
}


let result = repeatStringNumTimes("*", 5);

console.log(result)
```

te puede ayudar:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion

Comment: No olvides explicar brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Para algunos puede que parezca una obviedad, pero puede que otros no comprendan lo que hace. Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.